# Kotlin Error: Unresolved reference: merge (for list.merge())

Tags: kotlin

I have the following Kotlin code based on the code from the "Generation operations" section from [here](http://antonioleiva.com/collection-operations-kotlin/):

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val listRepeated = listOf(2,2,3,4,5,5,6)
println(list.merge(listRepeated) { it1, it2  -> it1 + it2 })
```

I am receiving the following error messages:

```
Error:(33, 18) Kotlin: Unresolved reference: merge
Error:(33, 40) Kotlin: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
Error:(33, 45) Kotlin: Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
```

How can I get this code to properly compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`merge` has been dropped in Kotlin 1.0 Beta 2 as described [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/11/kotlin-1-0-beta-2-is-out/).

As @tim_yates said, this code sample will give you the same output as in the article:

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val listRepeated = listOf(2,2,3,4,5,5,6)
println(list.zip(listRepeated) { it1, it2  -> it1 + it2 })
```

Comment: My idea is the same output as the article of "Antonio Leiva" about collection operations in kotlin ([this article](http://antonioleiva.com/collection-operations-kotlin/))

My English is week a bit and sorry if you understand my answer in a wrong way :)

Comment: Ahhh!  Tweaked the sentence so hopefully now it has the meaning you wanted :-)

Comment: Thanks for tweaking my answer :D

Comment: Thank you both very much.  I appreciate the links, and the code is working now.

Answer (score 5):

Can't find merge in the official docs (but do find it [mentioned here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/07/m8-is-out/))

Think you [want zip](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html):

```
println(list.zip(listRepeated) { it1, it2  -> it1 + it2 })
```